# How get rows and get count rows for each unique param in one sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

God day.

I use MsSQl Server 2008;

Code:

```
$entersql="SELECT name
FROM (
SELECT name FROM 
Hist_answer
WHERE id_city='$id_city' AND id_firm='$id_firm' AND id_service='$id_service'
) x
GROUP BY name
";

$enterres = sqlsrv_query($conn, $entersql, $params, $options);

while($i = sqlsrv_fetch_array($enterres, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC))
{

if($inputby=='id_hist_answer'&&$typeby=='DESC'){$a--;}else{$a++;}

$name=($i['name']!='')? $i['name']:'0';

$sql11="SELECT 
ha.unit as ha_unit,
ha.id_producer_goods as ha_id_producer_goods
FROM Hist_answer ha
WHERE ha.id_city='$id_city' AND ha.id_firm='$id_firm' AND ha.id_service='$id_service' AND ha.name='$name'";

$params = array();
$options =  array( "Scrollable" => SQLSRV_CURSOR_KEYSET );
$res11 = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql11,$params,$options);

$row_count_ha = sqlsrv_num_rows($res11);

}
```

In this code i do:

1) i selected all unique `name` (`group by name`);

2) in second sql($sql11) i do find count rows for each `name`.

***Tell me please how do sql when i can find all unique `name` (`group by name`) and count rows for each unique `name` ?***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get unique names and their counts in a single statement:

```
SELECT  name, count(name) AS records 
FROM    Hist_answer
WHERE   id_city='$id_city' 
    AND id_firm='$id_firm' 
    AND id_service='$id_service'
GROUP BY name
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  colname, count(colname) AS UniqueRecord_Count 
FROM    ascouser
GROUP BY colname
```

You can put your column name on which you wanna get count ,may be put Where clause for filtering records as you said.